# maven error: package org.mockito does not exist

Tags: java, maven

i am inside my project on the command line and i have tried doing mvn clean install but i get errors saying that the package org.mockito does not exist
even though i have this in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
           <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
           <version>1.9.5</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and so the build is consequently failing

Comment: You're only using mockito from test-scope, right? i.e. `src/test/java` rather than `src/main/java`.

Comment: try to remove "<scope>test</scope>" temporarily and try again.

Comment: can you add complete pom file  and your package structure project to pom also add your nexus is local or hiting global public maven ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, check your local repository whether the jar is available
2. If not available then please check the address of maven central repository and proxy settings are configured correctly in your `.m2/setting.xml`.